# How to protect the .php file with JSON object when accessed through url in the browser

Tags: php

I hope that this is not too difficult, so here is a story, I have created a simple process which is being sent as JSON object when requested, but for security reasons, would really like to protect (403) the content of the file if it is accessed by placing a full URL to it in the browser.

Here is a script inside my ajax.php

```
<?php
$image = array(
"/trial/images/1.png",
"/trial/images/2.png",
"/trial/images/3.png",
"/trial/images/4.png"
);
  $msg = array(
    'status' => 1,
    'message' => 'Remember to +1',
    'html' => '<p>Thank you for downloading our software <img src="'. $image[array_rand($image)] .'" width="80" height="80" alt="Thank You"></p>'
  );
  echo json_encode($msg);
?>
```

and here is a script of the function that I am using to POST with ajax into that file to obtain JSON object out.

```
function custom_reminder(aElem){
    theLink=$(aElem).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/includes/ajax.php",
        data:"action=reminder&thepath="+theLink,
        dataType:"json",
        error:function(){window.location=theLink;},
        success:function(msg){
            if(msg.status == 1) {
                display_reminder(msg.html,theLink);
            }else{
                custom_message(msg.message,"error");
                }
        }
    });
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This story should preventing from CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgivery Attack) with AJAX request.

1. You can put some header data and check on client for requested it.
2. Use session for checking a data from client and compare it with session on server for accessing on ajax request.
3. Add in code `strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')` to be sure is xmlhttprequested from ajax
4. Generate some tokens if you send sensitive data from server and store it on client with time limit

Example of token usage:

```
function checkToken( $userId, $eventIdentificator, $token){

       if( $token == sha1( $some_value_grabbed_from_time )){
       return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

5 . Add time limit user for requesting a data with some generated key so in future can't use with this hash key in GET and preventing attacking it.

Example of generate token:

```
protected static function _generateToken()
{
    $token = sha1(mt_rand(0, 1000000));
    $_SESSION[$token] = time();
    return $token;
}
```

And validate it as:

```
     if ($_SESSION[$token] >= time() - 7200) {
        $valid = true;
     }
```

6 . You can add into ajax with COOKIE combined as show on IT Security: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20015/protecting-against-csrf-when-a-form-is-being-submitted-via-an-ajax-call

7 . Look at example on Github as shown as simple class: https://github.com/foxbunny/CSRF4PHP

or ...

```
public function generateToken() {
    // Create or overwrite the csrf entry in the seesion
    $_SESSION['csrf'] = array();
    $_SESSION['csrf']['time'] = time();
    $_SESSION['csrf']['salt'] = $this->randomString(32);
    $_SESSION['csrf']['sessid'] = session_id();
    $_SESSION['csrf']['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    // Generate the SHA1 hash
    $hash = $this->calculateHash();
    // Generate and return the token
    return base64_encode($hash);
}

protected function checkTimeout($timeout=NULL) {
    if (!$timeout) {
        $timeout = $this->timeout;
    }
    return ($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] - $_SESSION['csrf']['time']) < $timeout;
}

public function checkToken($timeout=NULL) {
    // Default timeout is 300 seconds (5 minutes)

    // First check if csrf information is present in the session
    if (isset($_SESSION['csrf'])) {

        // Check the timeliness of the request
        if (!$this->checkTimeout($timeout)) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Check if there is a session id
        if (session_id()) {
            // Check if response contains a usable csrf token
            $isCsrfGet = isset($_GET['csrf']);
            $isCsrfPost = isset($_POST['csrf']);
            if (($this->acceptGet and $isCsrfGet) or $isCsrfPost) {
                // Decode the received token hash
                $tokenHash = base64_decode($_REQUEST['csrf']);
                // Generate a new hash from the data we have
                $generatedHash = $this->calculateHash();
                // Compare and return the result
                if ($tokenHash and $generatedHash) {
                    return $tokenHash == $generatedHash;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // In all other cases return FALSE
    return FALSE;
}
```

}

This source code show as best practices for preventing CSRF attacking on side Ajax request. It will check get/post of generated data sended from form and compare with hash putted on PHP object as static variable (`_generateToken()`)

8 .  `OWASP` shows from Web application project shows usable examples how is attacking via X/CSRF and examples usable how to preventing of them.

Link: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Mostly and often is on principle: "Double submitting cookies" when scripts sends on every request random generated ID and compares it from previous and new vars sended.

9 . Write your own SCRIPT for testing attacking with random string, use SHA512 for harder attacking, or use downloads for testing only: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_CSRFTester_Project

10 . Add some HTTP HEADER dummy data with round example time() and compares example is today ODD or EVEN day or ODD/EVEN hour/minutes....

11 . If attacked from ONE IP address often in some period of time example 3 minutes, alerts it to admin... or block temporary remoted host..

12 . If you STILL DON'T KNOW how X/CSRF works look at some examples of video on YT: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDXTDR6xew8

13 . If you want to know how to use with `crypt()` and some OLD SCHOOL CSRF prevention use as example: http://phpmaster.com/preventing-cross-site-request-forgeries/

or simple code:

```
session_start();

switch($_GET["action"]) {
    case "login":
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $user = (isset($_POST["user"]) &&
            ctype_alnum($_POST["user"]) ? $_POST["user"] : null;
        $pass = (isset($_POST["pass"])) ? $_POST["pass"] : null;
        $salt = '$2a$07$my.s3cr3t.SalTY.str1nG$';

        if (isset($user, $pass) && (crypt($user . $pass, $salt) ==
            crypt("admintest", $salt))) {
            $_SESSION["user"] = $_POST["user"];
        }
    }
    break;

    case "logout":
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    break;
}

header("Location: login.php");
```

14 . For CODEIGNITER/KOHANA users can use as simple via HOOKS (loaded as class before all of class), with examples of injection codes: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/protect-a-codeigniter-application-against-csrf/

15. Make protecting from INJECTION of code VIA JAVASCRIPT as:

    ```
    $output = preg_replace('/(<(form|FORM)[^>]*(method|METHOD)="(post|POST)"[^>]*>)/',  
                     '$0<input type="hidden" name="' . self::$token_name . '" value="' . self::$token . '">', $output);
    ```
16. Make put SSL data transfer when you send or receive using JSON data to prevent sniffing or looking data.
17. Put digitally sign such as hash into header based on content. Hash your content and put in a header file 'Digital-Sign: md5-data' for example. A content should be hashed and put into header as new variable for digital sign. A client than checks data and compares using hash for checking is true. You can combine with salt such with timestamp of send data. md5($timestasmp.$content)

Comment: WOW, yet again I have to thank this site and all admin and uses of this site for a great recourse

Comment: but how this prevents forging the request? you may simply forge all sent headers and cookies, so it's a protection from csrf, not from showing in browser what comes through AJAX.

Comment: If you combined spaghetti code you are well secured. Put some logs and alerts on `mail()` for additional attacks if persists from one IP address.

Comment: actually to be clear, the script I have is not used for mailing, it is used for placing a JSON object into Jquery UI Dialog, so I think that there should not be major security risks

Comment: @MarinSagovac in reality, what I am actually trying is much simpler, because all I am doing is displaying a dialog reminder to user who has clicked the download button on one page prior to allowing that user to proceed to the actual download page. My dialog simply displaying an image and some simple text as well as button to proceed with original request

Answer (score 1):

You could check the referer. If it's from the same host, serve the JSON file. Otherwise present the 403.

Other option could be with a secret,  based on a hash out of different values. Send them with the AJAX request and check them in your PHP file.

Comment: Both are not reliable. Referer may be simply forged (it's just a HTTP header), method of calculating hash can be read from jQuery code and also forged.

Comment: Yes, but it's a bit more safer than no check.

Comment: kinda like the "please do not steal this" sign on your valuable stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Use a session:

`$_SESSION['key'] = 'randomcode';`

Send an encrypted version of this key to your AJAX call.

Let the AJAX script match the received key with the session. If it matches, you know the request came from someone who visited your downloadpage.

Comment: whould this be creating a session in http headers?

Comment: it would add a cookie to your headers containing your session_id

Comment: which is automatically deleted when user leaves the page?

Comment: or should I use Klaus Hartl jquery_cookie.js to control the session?

Comment: yes, I think a session is lost when you close the last page of the visited website